# Is there a function in PHP that merges two multidimensional associative arrays?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Note, my thanks to those of you who responded.  Sorry to be tardy in responding, I have been ill since I posted this, and I am afraid I did not make this example very clear.  Let's try again:

Using PHP, I have two, two-dimensional associative arrays which I want to combine into one array with all the fields, see example below

```
$ary_0[0]['name'] = 'Bobby', $ary_0[0]['address'] = '123 E Park Place'
$ary_0[1]['name'] = 'Chris', $ary_0[1]['address'] = '13 Bonanza Trail'
$ary_0[2]['name'] = 'Sally', $ary_0[2]['address'] = '97 West 3rd Ave.'

$ary_1[0]['name'] = 'Bobby', $ary_1[0]['phone'] = '555-555-1212'
$ary_1[1]['name'] = 'Chris', $ary_1[1]['phone'] = '222-555-1212'
$ary_1[2]['name'] = 'Sally', $ary_1[2]['phone'] = '999-555-1212'
```

so that the resulting array looks like

```
$ary_2[0]['name'] = 'Bobby', $ary_2[0]['address'] = '123 E Park Place', $ary_2[0]['phone'] = '555-555-1212'
$ary_2[1]['name'] = 'Chris', $ary_2[1]['address'] = '13 Bonanza Trail', $ary_2[1]['phone'] = '222-555-1212'
$ary_2[2]['name'] = 'Sally', $ary_2[2]['address'] = '97 West 3rd Ave.', $ary_2[2]['phone'] = '999-555-1212'
```

Notice that the two arrays are already sorted by name, and the name field is the join on the two arrays.  In fact, this data is being extracted from two disparate databases and cannot be conventionally joined as tables, but that is the effect I am seeking.

Is there a function in PHP which will merge these two arrays like this?  I have been all over the literature but can't find a workable solution other than brute-forcing the name values to look for a match.
Anybody out there have an elegant and simple solution?  I don't believe that array_merge() will work...

TIA,
Mike

Comment: Your question is somehow very unclear to me

Comment: So, you want to join the elements not by key, but by the value of `name`? Anyway, assigning multiple times `$ary[0]` is actually replacing the values, you have only the last values of each key there.

Comment: @Gabriel, that's correct.

Comment: Since they are already sorted by name, can you do a for loop and use http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php? Your data structure isn't perfectly clear.

Comment: According to your question the array element `$ary[0][name]` seems to have three different values. An assignment like this would simply overwrite a previously defined value and only the last assignment would prevail.

Answer (score 0):

Since they are already sorted by name, can you do a for loop and use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) ?

```
$combined_arr = [];
for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $1 ); $i++ ) {
    combined_arr[] = array_merge( arr[0], arr[1] );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets rewrite the array so its more clear for everybody, assuming that your code was just some pseudocode thus ignoring the syntax and the repeated keys errors.

```
$ary=[
    ['name'=>'Bobby','address'=>'123 E Park Place'],
    ['name'=>'Chris','address'=>'13 Bonanza Trail'],
    ['name'=>'Sally','address'=>'97 West 3rd Ave.'],
    ['name'=>'Bobby','phone'=>'555-555-1212'],
    ['name'=>'Chris','phone'=>'222-555-1212'],
    ['name'=>'Sally','phone'=>'999-555-1212']
];
```

This would give you *almost* what you currently have.

There's no way to do it with a builtin function, it's something too specific. 
But solving this is quite simple.

```
$newArray=[];
foreach($ary as $key=>$val) {
    $found=false;
    foreach($newArray as $nKey=>$nVal) {
        if($nVal['name']==$val['name']) {
            $found=true;
            $newArray[$nKey]=array_merge($nVal,$val);
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!$found) $newArray[]=$val;
}
```

If you have too many elements and need something more efficient, you should redesign your array or implement other search algorithm or use a database with indexes.

*Note that the `[]` notation will only work on PHP +5.4.*